# MySQL bringing back multiple totals

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have simple MySQL Query:

```
SELECT who, status, 
COUNT(status) AS Total, completion_status AS Role
FROM `trespondent_360` 
GROUP BY who, status 
ORDER BY who, status
```

This correctly brings back to the total in the database for each person.  I need to then count the Total where their completion_status ='s either Started or Complete.

The output should be something like:

```
Who          Total          Status          Completed
Mike Smith   1              Self            1
Mike Smith   5              Other           2
Bob Jones    1              Self            0
Bob Jones    6              Other           5
```

Whenever I add to the above code, I get the error that **the Operand should contain 1 column(s)**.  See below

```
SELECT who, status, 
COUNT(status) AS Total, completion_status AS Role,
(SELECT who, status, COUNT(status) FROM `trespondent_360` 
  WHERE completion_status IN ('Started','Complete')) AS Completed
FROM `trespondent_360` 
GROUP BY who, status 
ORDER BY who, status
```

Any advice and feedback on what I need to do would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to count status `Complete` or `Started` you can use `CASE WHEN`:

```
SELECT who, status, 
       completion_status AS Role,
       COUNT(status) AS Total,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN status IN ('Started','Complete') THEN 1 END) AS Completed
FROM `trespondent_360` 
GROUP BY who, status 
ORDER BY who, status;
```

By the way you should use aggregation function on `completion_status` column, I know it works with MySQL but it is not ANSI compliant. **[`More info why you should do it`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33629168/group-by-clause-in-mysql-and-postgresql-why-the-error-in-postgresql/33629201#33629201)**

Comment: Appreciate the note on the `aggregation` function as well.