# SQL Distinct keyword not returning distinct values for Multiple Columns

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

If i select only 1 column with Distinct then it's working fine if i select multiple columns with 1 distinct it returns duplicate values ..

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT MS.SRC_TABLE_NAME AS SRC_TABLE_NAME,
    MS.SRC_SYSTEM_ENVIRONMENT_NAME AS SRC_SYSTEM_ENVIRONMENT_NAME,
    MS.SRC_SYSTEM_NAME AS SRC_SYSTEM_NAME
FROM
    MAPPING_SPECIFICATION MS,
    MAPPING_DETAILS MD

WHERE
    MS.MAP_ID = MD.MAP_ID AND
    MD.STATUS = 'Active'
```

Returns Duplicate rows

```
 SELECT
        DISTINCT MS.SRC_TABLE_NAME AS SRC_TABLE_NAME        
    FROM
        MAPPING_SPECIFICATION MS,
        MAPPING_DETAILS MD

    WHERE
        MS.MAP_ID = MD.MAP_ID AND
        MD.STATUS = 'Active'
```

Works Perfectly if select only Distinct Row .

Comment: Duplicate on what?is it on `SRC_SYSTEM_ENVIRONMENT_NAME`?

Comment: @SubinCPoonamgode MS.SRC_TABLE_NAME .. that i need only unique

Comment: What database are you using?  Please tag your question appropriately.  Also, clarify what you want to return.  `DISTINCT` is working fine.  You just don't understand what it does.

Comment: Which database? Also try to avoid comma seperated JOINS!

Answer (score 1):

`DISTINCT` does not guarantee you have `SRC_TABLE_NAME` unique when you use it with other columns. Your rows are `DISTINCT` and it works perfectly fine

```
CREATE TABLE #MyTable(col1 INT, col2 INT);

INSERT INTO #MyTable VALUES (1,1), (1,2), (2,1),(3,1);

SELECT DISTINCT col1, col2
FROM #MyTable;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/387950)**</kbd>

Use `GROUP BY` instead with **[`aggregate function`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html)** like `MIN/MAX/GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
SELECT
    MS.SRC_TABLE_NAME AS SRC_TABLE_NAME,
    MIN(MS.SRC_SYSTEM_ENVIRONMENT_NAME) AS SRC_SYSTEM_ENVIRONMENT_NAME,
    MIN(MS.SRC_SYSTEM_NAME) AS SRC_SYSTEM_NAME
FROM MAPPING_SPECIFICATION MS
JOIN MAPPING_DETAILS MD
  ON MS.MAP_ID = MD.MAP_ID AND
WHERE MD.STATUS = 'Active'
GROUP BY MS.SRC_TABLE_NAME;
```

Also try to avoid comma syntax join and use `JOIN`. Keep in mind that `SQL Server` and `MySQL` support different aggregate functions.

Comment: sorry, I rushed with the question. Saw multiple selects and and groupped by one single field. Then i saw those multiple selects were aggregate functions. So it can be sql server

Comment: @CM2K You probably want to write about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33629168/group-by-clause-in-mysql-and-postgresql-why-the-error-in-postgresql/33629201#33629201. MySQL allows column without grouping, SQL Server not. Good point.

Comment: exactly, those kind of answers are very useful

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this to get DISTINCT with multiple columns:

```
select 
(SELECT group_concat(DISTINCT MS.SRC_TABLE_NAME) FROM MAPPING_SPECIFICATION MS INNER JOIN MAPPING_DETAILS MD ON MS.MAP_ID = MD.MAP_ID 
WHERE MD.STATUS = 'Active') as SRC_TABLE_NAME,
(SELECT group_concat(DISTINCT MS.SRC_SYSTEM_ENVIRONMENT_NAME) FROM MAPPING_SPECIFICATION MS INNER JOIN MAPPING_DETAILS MD ON MS.MAP_ID = MD.MAP_ID 
WHERE MD.STATUS = 'Active') as SRC_SYSTEM_ENVIRONMENT_NAME,
(SELECT group_concat(DISTINCT MS.SRC_SYSTEM_NAM) FROM MAPPING_SPECIFICATION MS INNER JOIN MAPPING_DETAILS MD ON MS.MAP_ID = MD.MAP_ID 
WHERE MD.STATUS = 'Active') as SRC_SYSTEM_NAME
```

Its in MYSQL.

In SQL Server you can use Group By like this:

```
SELECT MS.SRC_SYSTEM_NAM AS SRC_TABLE_NAME,
          MS.SRC_SYSTEM_ENVIRONMENT_NAME AS SRC_SYSTEM_ENVIRONMENT_NAME,
          MS.SRC_SYSTEM_NAME AS SRC_SYSTEM_NAME
   FROM MAPPING_SPECIFICATION MS 
        INNER JOIN MAPPING_DETAILS MD ON MS.MAP_ID = MD.MAP_ID 
   WHERE MD.STATUS = 'Active'
   GROUP BY MS.SRC_SYSTEM_NAM, MS.SRC_SYSTEM_ENVIRONMENT_NAME, MS.SRC_SYSTEM_NAME
```