# Why does this query return an intermediate record?

Tags: mysql

I ran a somewhat nonsense query on MySQL, but because its output is the same each time, I'm wondering if someone can help me understand the underlying algorithm.

Here's the table `Orders` on which we'll execute the query (database taken from [here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-sample-database.aspx), just in case someone's interested):

```
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field          | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| orderNumber    | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| orderDate      | date        | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| requiredDate   | date        | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| shippedDate    | date        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| status         | varchar(15) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| comments       | text        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| customerNumber | int(11)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

There are 326 records for now, with the largest `orderNumber` being 10425.

Now here's the query I ran (basically removed `GROUP BY` from a sensible query):

```
mysql> select count(1), orderNumber, status from orders;
+----------+-------------+---------+
| count(1) | orderNumber | status  |
+----------+-------------+---------+
|      326 |       10100 | Shipped |
+----------+-------------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

So I'm asking for the total number of rows, along with `status` and `orderNumber`, which can be just about anything under the given circumstances. But the query always returns `orderNumber 10100`, even if I log out and run it again.

Is there a predictable answer for this?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33629168/group-by-clause-in-mysql-and-postgresql-why-the-error-in-postgresql/33629201#33629201

Comment: @lad2025 Excellent link!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no predictable answer for which you should use in your design.  In general, the DB will return the values of the first row that matches the query.  If you want predictability, you should apply an aggregate to every column (e.g. using MIN or MAX to always get smallest/largest value)

Comment: Oh, crap! Didn't cross my mind that this could be the first or last record in the table. Thanks for the answer!