# COUNT field incorrect or syntax error

Tags: sql-server, pdo

What would be the error when I get following error message

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[07002]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]COUNT field incorrect or syntax error'...

This is the query I'm using

```
$sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT stockamount, stockname, stockbalance.stockid, SUM(ABS(reservationtransaction.stockquantity)) AS reservedamount FROM stockbalance
    JOIN stock ON stockbalance.stockid = stock.stockid
    LEFT JOIN reservationtransaction ON reservationtransaction.articleid = :artid
    WHERE stockbalance.articleid = :artid AND ((changeddate > DATEADD(yy,-1,GETDATE()) AND inventorydate > DATEADD(yy,-1,GETDATE())) OR stockbalance.stockamount <> 0)
    GROUP BY stockbalance.stockid");
$sql->bindValue(':artid', $productId);
$sql->execute();
```

I have searched questions in SO, but no one was similar or helpful.
Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** This query is working fine when executing it with Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, but when using PDO, I'm getting the error.

Comment: Your `stockamount` and `stockname` are not part of the `GROUP BY` so you cannot select them without an aggregate method like `MIN`.

Comment: I guess you have MySQL background :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33629168/group-by-clause-in-mysql-and-postgresql-why-the-error-in-postgresql/33629201#33629201. The point is MySQL aggregation behaviour isn't ANSI complaint.

Comment: Per the error message, this is a PDOException, not a SQL Exception.   Could it be a mismatch in the result set, and the object you're trying to bind it to?

Comment: @TabAlleman, everything works ok when I'm executing this with Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, but when using PDO, I'm getting this error. I also tried without `bindValue()` and writing values to the query - same error.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

> The number of parameters specified in SQLBindParameter was less than
>   the number of parameters in the SQL statement contained in
>   *StatementText. SQLBindParameter was called with ParameterValuePtr set to a null pointer, StrLen_or_IndPtr not set to SQL_NULL_DATA or
>   SQL_DATA_AT_EXEC, and InputOutputType not set to SQL_PARAM_OUTPUT, so
>   that the number of parameters specified in SQLBindParameter was
>   greater than the number of parameters in the SQL statement contained
>   in *StatementText. [SQLExecute Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms713584(v=vs.85).aspx)

placeholders must have unique names even if they have the same value

```
$sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT stockamount, stockname, stockbalance.stockid, SUM(ABS(reservationtransaction.stockquantity)) AS reservedamount FROM stockbalance
JOIN stock ON stockbalance.stockid = stock.stockid
LEFT JOIN reservationtransaction ON reservationtransaction.articleid = :artid
WHERE stockbalance.articleid = :artid2 AND ((changeddate > DATEADD(yy,-1,GETDATE()) AND inventorydate > DATEADD(yy,-1,GETDATE())) OR stockbalance.stockamount <> 0)
GROUP BY stockbalance.stockid");
$sql->bindValue(':artid', $productId);
$sql->bindValue(':artid2', $productId);
$sql->execute();
```

Comment: This was the problem! Thanks for your answer.

Comment: You have no idea how much time this answer has saved me! Thank's a lot!!!

Comment: Why Microsoft would make the developer's life *easier*, let them burn in *bind parameters** hell ?!

Answer (score 6):

Another possibility, if you want to avoid supplying data multiple times (replace the datatype of @artid with the correct data type):

```
$sql = $pdo->prepare("DECLARE @artid int = :artid
    SELECT stockamount, stockname, stockbalance.stockid, SUM(ABS(reservationtransaction.stockquantity)) AS reservedamount FROM stockbalance
    JOIN stock ON stockbalance.stockid = stock.stockid
    LEFT JOIN reservationtransaction ON reservationtransaction.articleid = @artid
    WHERE stockbalance.articleid = @artid AND ((changeddate > DATEADD(yy,-1,GETDATE()) AND inventorydate > DATEADD(yy,-1,GETDATE())) OR stockbalance.stockamount <> 0)
    GROUP BY stockbalance.stockid");
$sql->bindValue(':artid', $productId);
$sql->execute();
```

This will only work in an RDBMS that supports DECLARE statements.

Answer (score 1):

All the columns that are not in any arithmetic function must go in the `GROUP BY` clause. see below:

```
SELECT stockamount, 
       stockname, 
       stockbalance.stockid, 
       Sum(Abs(reservationtransaction.stockquantity)) AS reservedamount 
FROM   stockbalance 
       INNER JOIN stock 
               ON stockbalance.stockid = stock.stockid 
       LEFT JOIN reservationtransaction 
              ON reservationtransaction.articleid = :artid 
WHERE  stockbalance.articleid = :artid 
       AND ( ( changeddate > Dateadd(yy, -1, Getdate()) 
               AND inventorydate > Dateadd(yy, -1, Getdate()) ) 
              OR stockbalance.stockamount <> 0 ) 
GROUP  BY stockamount, 
          stockname, 
          stockbalance.stockid
```

Comment: Ok, I tried that, but it doesn't help. I'm still getting error `SQLSTATE[07002]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]COUNT field incorrect or syntax error`.

Answer (score 1):

While GROUP BY is often the culprit for a COUNT issue, I ran into the subject error in SSRS and it was due to a mismatch between the SSRS dataset query and the parameters. The resolution was to ensure each WHERE in the query had a corresponding parameter for the dataset. (I had missed one.)

Answer (score 1):

We had this error when a Django filter statement was trying to substitute more parameters in a query than could be handled by the DB binary. Our query looked roughly like this:

`select name, age from Employee where emp_id in (%s)`

from a Django statement

`Employee.objects.filter(emp_id__in=employee_ids)`

The list of emp_id was about 2,100 elements. (The character length of the params substituted was about 10,500).

The hack was to filter in parts and recombine the subsets.