# group by clause is not working

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT 
    dm.DISTRICT_NAME ,      
    od.REGULAR_WORKERS_COUNT,
    od.DAILY_OR_CASUAL_WORKERS_COUNT,
    od.CONTRACT_WORKERS_COUNT,
    od.TOTAL_COUNT
FROM
    ORG_DETAILS od with (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN 
    DISTRICT_MASTER dm with (NOLOCK) ON od.DISTRICT_ID = dm.DISTRICT_ID
GROUP BY
    dm.district_name
```

I had this code, and I am looking to group my table with district_name. I am getting an error though.

Error message :

> Column 'ORG_DETAILS.REGULAR_WORKERS_COUNT' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: SQL Server is not MySQL. You need to use agg function in every column that is not specified in GROUP BY or GROUP BY multiple columns. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33629168/group-by-clause-in-mysql-and-postgresql-why-the-error-in-postgresql

Comment: It is not "group by clause not working", but you're using it incorrectly. Error text is self-explanatory, read it precisely and think what does it means.

Comment: @AndyKorneyev thank you...

Comment: And stop using `WITH (NOLOCK)`. Based on your misunderstanding of a `GROUP BY` clause, I'm guessing you have don't understand `NOLOCK` either

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:-

```
SELECT 
    dm.DISTRICT_NAME ,      
    COUNT(od.REGULAR_WORKERS_COUNT),
    COUNT(od.DAILY_OR_CASUAL_WORKERS_COUNT),
    COUNT(od.CONTRACT_WORKERS_COUNT),
    COUNT(od.TOTAL_COUNT)
FROM 
    ORG_DETAILS od with (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN 
    DISTRICT_MASTER dm with (NOLOCK) ON od.DISTRICT_ID = dm.DISTRICT_ID
GROUP BY 
    dm.district_name
```

Comment: really thanks for your help.  i am getting the count ... but . i need the values in the columns to be added when i group two columns of same district_name

Comment: i have got it by replacing "count" with "sum"... thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    dm.DISTRICT_NAME ,      
    sum(od.REGULAR_WORKERS_COUNT),
    sum(od.DAILY_OR_CASUAL_WORKERS_COUNT),
    sum(od.CONTRACT_WORKERS_COUNT),
    sum(od.TOTAL_COUNT)
FROM 
    ORG_DETAILS od with (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN 
    DISTRICT_MASTER dm with (NOLOCK) ON od.DISTRICT_ID = dm.DISTRICT_ID
GROUP BY 
    dm.district_name
```