# How to select sum of count of distinct values in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, distinct

This is my Query :

```
SELECT 
    p.PRO_Id, p.PRO_Name,
    COUNT(DISTINCT c.COM_Id) as commentCount,
    COUNT(DISTINCT d.DIS_Id) AS disCount, 
    d.DIS_ThreadDesc,
    dev.DEV_Name,
    loc.LOC_Name,
    d.USE_Id,
    d.DIS_Date
FROM projects p
LEFT JOIN discussions d ON p.PRO_Id = d.PRO_Id
LEFT JOIN comments c ON d.DIS_Id = c.DIS_Id
LEFT JOIN developer dev ON p.DEV_Id=dev.DEV_Id
LEFT JOIN locality loc ON p.LOC_Id=loc.LOC_Id
WHERE p.PRO_Status=1 
  and d.DIS_Status=1 
  and c.COM_Status=2
GROUP BY p.PRO_Id
ORDER  BY 3 desc LIMIT 3
```

What i'm trying to get is the sum of commenCount(total comments) and disCount(total discussions).
 I tried like this;-

```
 sum(COUNT(DISTINCT c.COM_Id) + COUNT(DISTINCT d.DIS_Id)) AS totalResponse
```

but no chance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add result of both `COUNT`s:

```
SELECT 
    p.PRO_Id, p.PRO_Name,
    COUNT(DISTINCT c.COM_Id) AS commentCount,
    COUNT(DISTINCT d.DIS_Id) AS disCount, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT c.COM_Id) + COUNT(DISTINCT d.DIS_Id) AS totalResponse
    d.DIS_ThreadDesc, dev.DEV_Name, loc.LOC_Name, d.USE_Id, d.DIS_Date
FROM projects p
...
```

alternatively using subquery:

```
SELECT sub.*,
       commentCount + disCount AS totalResponse
FROM (
  SELECT 
    p.PRO_Id, p.PRO_Name,
    COUNT(DISTINCT c.COM_Id) as commentCount,
    COUNT(DISTINCT d.DIS_Id) AS disCount, 
    d.DIS_ThreadDesc,
    dev.DEV_Name,
    loc.LOC_Name,
    d.USE_Id,
    d.DIS_Date
  FROM projects p
  LEFT JOIN discussions d ON p.PRO_Id = d.PRO_Id
  LEFT JOIN comments c ON d.DIS_Id = c.DIS_Id
  LEFT JOIN developer dev ON p.DEV_Id=dev.DEV_Id
  LEFT JOIN locality loc ON p.LOC_Id=loc.LOC_Id
  WHERE p.PRO_Status=1 
   and d.DIS_Status=1 
   and c.COM_Status=2
  GROUP BY p.PRO_Id
) AS sub
ORDER BY commentCount LIMIT 3
```

Keep in mind that your `SELECT` list and `GROUP BY` does not match. This will work for `MySQL` but is not compliant with `ANSI` standard. You should have the same list in both clauses or use aggregate functions for columns that are not specified in `GROUP BY`. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33629201/5070879).

Comment: May be its time for me to think straight forward.

Comment: @Plum: Yes. Understand that `SUM()` is intended to sum the values within a column. If you wanna add the values, think straightforward and use the humble `+`.