# Get list of ids for each in group in group by statement sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite

Let's suppose I have a sqlite table like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    field1 INTEGER,
    field2 INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO my_table (field1, field2) VALUES
    (1, 2),
    (2, 1),
    (2, 1),
    (3, 1),
    (1, 2),
    (2, 1);
```

Which looks like:

```
1|1|2
2|2|1
3|2|1
4|3|1
5|1|2
6|2|1
```

For each group of distinct values where the group size is larger than 1, I would like the set of corresponding ids. For the above this would be: `1,5` and `2,3,6`.

If I run

```
SELECT id FROM my_table
GROUP BY
    field1, field2
HAVING count(*) > 1;
```

only the last for each group is returned, i.e. `5` and `6`. Can I return **all** the ids for each group?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Without aggregation function you could get any value. [SQLite is similiar to MySQL in that matter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33629201/5070879). In standard SQL you have to choose aggregation function, otherwise you will get error.

To get all values you could use [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html):

```
SELECT field1, field2, GROUP_CONCAT(id, ',') AS ids
FROM my_table
GROUP BY field1, field2
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/36828/6/0)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔═════════╦═════════╦═══════╗
║ field1  ║ field2  ║  ids  ║
╠═════════╬═════════╬═══════╣
║      1  ║      2  ║ 1,5   ║
║      2  ║      1  ║ 2,3,6 ║
╚═════════╩═════════╩═══════╝
```

If you want `ids` only remove `field1,field2` from select columns list.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id, ',') AS ids
FROM my_table
GROUP BY field1, field2
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo2`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/36828/7/0)**</kbd>