# MySQL Group By functionality in different version

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions, mysql-error-1055

Following is a simple SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM *table_name*
GROUP BY *column_name*
```

In my system I have MySQL 5.5. It is working absolutely fine. 
Whereas in my friend's system he have MySQL 5.7, and he is getting the following error:

> ERROR 1055 (42000): Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY
>   clause and contains nonaggregated column 'testdb.assetentry.entryId'
>   which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause;
>   this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

It is clearly visible this is happening because the versions are different.

But what I want to know is the reason behind this.

Can any one please explain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, please read [Group by clause in mySQL and postgreSQL, why the error in postgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33629168/group-by-clause-in-mysql-and-postgresql-why-the-error-in-postgresql)

It is not SQL Standard behaviour.

> [12.16.3 MySQL Handling of GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-handling.html)
>
> **To disable the MySQL GROUP BY extension and enable standard SQL behavior, enable the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY SQL mode**. In this case, columns not named in the GROUP BY clause cannot be used in the select list or HAVING clause unless enclosed in an aggregate function.

It looks like on second server you have acitivated `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` mode.

```
SELECT @@sql_mode;
```

You could simulate this behaviour on your `MySQL 5.5`:

```
SET SESSION sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY';

SELECT *
FROM tab
GROUP BY col;
-- tab.col2' isn't in GROUP BY
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/558433/3/2)**</kbd>

---

From [MySQL 5.7](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html):

> Implementation of the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY SQL mode has been made more
>   sophisticated, to no longer reject deterministic queries that
>   previously were rejected. **In consequence, ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is now
>   enabled by default, to prohibit nondeterministic queries containing
>   expressions not guaranteed to be uniquely determined within a group.**

Comment: ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is enabled by default on 5.7 (which is a good thing, but will be breaking a lot of old MySQL applications)

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Thanks, I added this to answer

Comment: @LukaszSzozda Can u please explain and why it is not work in the latest version 8.0 of MySQL?

Comment: @sunil MySQL 8.0 has ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY enabled by default as well. You need to write a query that have all columns defined in `GROUP BY` or wrapped with aggregation functions.