# MySQL `SUM` with `GROUP BY` is missing data in results

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database with a table containing information on some images, each row containing a `createdAt` date and a `viewCount`. The data ranges from September 2014 until today (July 2016). I want to get a monthly sum of the amount of views across all images for the month

When I run the query

```
SELECT YEAR(createdAt), MONTH(createdAt), SUM(viewCount) 
FROM Images 
GROUP BY MONTH(createdAt);
```

I'm only returned 12 rows with results between September 2014 and August 2015

```
Year | Month | Views
------------------- 
2014 |  9    | 1452 
2014 |  10   | 279 
2014 |  11   | 34428
2014 |  12   | 4763 
2015 |  1    | 2826 
2015 |  2    | 777 
2015 |  3    | 568 
2015 |  4    | 1309 
2015 |  5    | 46744 
2015 |  6    | 1541 
2015 |  7    | 8160 
2015 |  8    | 91
```

If I add a date restraint it will give me the latest data, but again only 12 rows

```
SELECT YEAR(createdAt), MONTH(createdAt), SUM(viewCount) 
FROM Images WHERE createdAt > DATE('2015-08-01 00:00:00')
GROUP BY MONTH(createdAt);

Year | Month | Views
--------------------
2015 |  8   | 981
2015 |  9   | 1031
2015 |  10  | 2566
2015 |  11  | 3325
2015 |  12  | 411    
2016 |  1   | 2140
2016 |  2   | 710
2016 |  3   | 714
2016 |  4   | 1985
2016 |  5   | 426
2016 |  6   | 119
2016 |  7   | 81
```

I do realise that since it's July the second query stops there as that's where the data ends, but why does the first query not return all the results?

Comment: Judging by what it appears you want, try also grouping by `YEAR(createdAt)` as well in your first query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by year/month:

```
SELECT YEAR(createdAt), MONTH(createdAt), SUM(viewCount) 
FROM Images 
--WHERE createdAt > DATE('2015-08-01 00:00:00')
GROUP BY YEAR(createdAt), MONTH(createdAt);
```

Related [Group by clause in mySQL and postgreSQL, why the error in postgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33629201/5070879)

Keep in mind that from MySQL 5.7.6+ your initial query may not even work because of `only_full_group_by` which is set by default.

Comment: That gave me all the results (removing the WHERE clause of course)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add Year to you group by

```
 SELECT YEAR(createdAt), MONTH(createdAt), SUM(viewCount) 
 FROM Images 
 GROUP BY YEAR(createdAt), MONTH(createdAt)
 ORDER BY YEAR(createdAt), MONTH(createdAt)
```