# Laravel query builder group by error: Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, query-builder, laravel-query-builder

I'm building a forum. I have two models: Thread and Report.

A thread can be reported multiple times by different users.

I'm working on a page to display the threads that have been reported to moderators.

Now the problem is that I would group the reports by threads so that it shows how many times a single thread has been reported and the same thread doesn't show up multiple times if it has been reported multiple times.

Reports table:

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->unsignedInteger('thread_id');
```

Threads table:

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->string('title', 500);
```

Relationship Reports -> Threads

```
 public function thread() {
    return $this->hasOne(Thread::class, 'id');
 }
```

So I do this:

```
Report::with('thread')
        ->groupBy('thread_id')
        ->get();
```

However, I get this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'reports.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by (SQL: select * from `reports` group by `thread_id`)
```

Any idea how to fix this or approach it in another way? Thanks!

Comment: [Group by clause in mySQL and postgreSQL, why the error in postgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33629168/group-by-clause-in-mysql-and-postgresql-why-the-error-in-postgresql) With `sql_mode=only_full_group_by` you need to wrap every column with agg function.

Comment: It's hard to say without having some idea of your intentions.  It doesn't make any sense to group by something without also selecting an aggregate (sum, count, etc...).  Can you explain a little more about what you are trying to do/achieve exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this:

**first:**
create a relationship in thread model like this:

```
public function reports() {
    return $this->hasMany(Report::class);
}
```

**second:**

- in the controller will get all threads that have at least one report with reports count, like this:

> $threads = Thread::has('reports')->withCount('reports')->get()

- in the view you can print it out like this

> @foreach($threads as $thread)
>   {{ $thread->id . ' has '  . $thread->reports_count . ' report'}}
>   @endforeach

Comment: This is it. Thank you very much, fantastic solution.

Comment: One more question. I would like to sort the results by the date of the reports so that the threads that have been reported first show up first. Is this doable this way?

Comment: @Hillcow add new column in the  `threads` table and name it something like this `last_report_at` and update it when new report is created,
 then use that column to order by it

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this works:

```
Report::with('thread')
    ->get()
    ->groupBy('thread_id');
```