# How to check all array elements exists in Where In Clause in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, query-builder

I am facing one problem  for creating one sql query. Actually i want to check if wherein clause  Exists all elements or not, If all elements exists in WhereIn clause then i want to return that records with groupby.. Here is my one table produt_categories :-

```
id product_id  category_id
 1    1              1
 2    1              2
```

Sow when i apply Wherein Like below:-

```
SELECT * FROM `product_categories` 
WHERE  category_id in (1,2,3) group by(product_id);
```

Now it return me this result:-

```
id product_id  category_id
 1    1              1
```

Actually its returning me fine because actual behavior of whereIn clause.
So i want if all category_id 1,2,3 exists then it must show records. If i pass 1,2 then i will also come. Hope you guys understand.Please help me to create qyuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `HAVING`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `product_categories` 
WHERE  category_id in (1,2,3) 
group by(product_id)
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT category_id) = 3;  -- #elements from `IN` clause
```

---

`SELECT * FROM tab GROUP BY col` is an anti-pattern.

Related article: [Group by clause in mySQL and postgreSQL, why the error in postgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33629168/group-by-clause-in-mysql-and-postgresql-why-the-error-in-postgresql)

Comment: unfortunaltely it will not work on dyanmic arrays Supose i pass element like this 1,2,3,4,5 and so on

Comment: its static.. please try to do with dyanmic suppose i have 10 elements of array then query will not work

Comment: @kunal That is why you need to specify the number according to array elements. Treat 3 as parameter.

Comment: you mean to say firstly i will check with count($array).. is n't it? then i will pass in sql query

Comment: @kunal Yes, something like that

Comment: do have knowledge of laravel?

Comment: @kunal None, I have no experience with PHP/Laravel at all.