# Foxpro VS SQL Logic

Tags: t-sql, foxpro

I couldn't think of a better title. If you have any suggestions, feel free to edit the title of my post.

I have a foxpro query that looks like this:

```
Sele
 a.plan_enddt as enddt, a.plrevno, a.keyfld, "PLAN    " as source ;
    from a_plan a inner join c_temp1a_pre b ;
    on a.keyfld=b.keyfld and a.plrevno=b.plrevno ;
    into cursor c_temp1a ;
    group by a.keyfld ;
    where a.plan_enddt>=date1 ;
```

What I am trying to do is translate from foxpro into T-SQL.

Wouldn't this foxpro statement fail because only 1 column is listed in the group by?

Edit:

I am not looking for a solution to fixing my foxpro statement

In TSQL, you can't just group by 1 column if you have multiple in the select statement, even if you aren't using an aggregate function.

Is this also true in Foxpro?

Comment: VFP allowed what you're showing through version 7, and added the restriction in version 8.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
Select MIN(a.plan_enddt) as enddt, MIN(a.plrevno), a.keyfld, 'PLAN    ' as [source]
from a_plan a 
inner join c_temp1a_pre b
  on a.keyfld=b.keyfld 
 and a.plrevno=b.plrevno 
where a.plan_enddt>=date1
group by a.keyfld ;
```

> *"I am not looking for a solution to fixing my foxpro statement"*

This is the same case as between MySQL and PostgreSQL: [Group by clause in mySQL and postgreSQL, why the error in postgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33629201/5070879)

> **SQL99 and later permits such nonaggregates per optional feature T301 if they are functionally dependent on GROUP BY columns**

[T-SQL 2.1.2.221 T301, Functional dependencies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh544322(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: That is very similar to what I posted already. Wouldn't more columns be required in the group by?

Comment: @LunchBox Yes, you have 2 options use AGG func on columns that are not in group by or add them to group  by clause

Comment: You edited your post after I posted.  Let me edit my original post

Comment: Edited my original post. I'm not really looking for a way to fix my statement. I just wanted to know if it is possible because it's not possible in TSQL.

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Bingo

Comment: @LunchBox Not every RDBMS implements T301 feature

Answer (score 0):

It looks as bug in Foxpro (Visual Foxpro 8 and earlier) to accept such invalid group by clause. All fields listed in select that are not aggregate values should be also part of group by fields.

Like this:

`select
 min(a.plan_enddt) as enddt, min(a.plrevno) as plrevno, a.keyfld, "PLAN    " as source 
    from a_plan a inner join c_temp1a_pre b 
    on a.keyfld=b.keyfld and a.plrevno=b.plrevno 
    into cursor c_temp1a 
    group by a.keyfld 
    where a.plan_enddt>=date1 ;`

or this:

`select
 a.plan_enddt as enddt, a.plrevno, a.keyfld, "PLAN    " as source 
    from a_plan a inner join c_temp1a_pre b 
    on a.keyfld=b.keyfld and a.plrevno=b.plrevno 
    into cursor c_temp1a 
    group by a.keyfld, a.plan_enddt, a.plrevno
    where a.plan_enddt>=date1 ;`

But in this case you can get more than one record, there is group by few fields.

Comment: It's not a bug, it just didn't follow the standard closely enough.