# How to acquire the same result without disabling ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

The following query is done after disabling `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` in MySQL. Now I want the same result without disabling `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` mode like `GROUP BY r.user_id, u.fullname, r.time_taken`

```
SELECT u.fullname, ROUND(AVG(r.correct), 2) avg_correct, date_format(r.time_taken,'%d-%m-%Y') time_taken
FROM (SELECT user_id, concat( first_name, ' ', last_name) fullname from user) u
LEFT JOIN test_result r ON u.user_id = r.user_id
GROUP BY r.user_id
ORDER BY r.time_taken DESC
```

Screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Values for r.correct and r.time_taken are arbitrary. You have to define a logic which value to choose MIN/MAX/.... Related [Group by clause in mySQL and postgreSQL, why the error in postgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33629201/5070879)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must add `u.fullname` to the `group by` clause and this does not affect the results as the user's id and fullname are uniquely grouped together, but in the case of  `time_taken` you must use [`any_value()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_any-value):

```
SELECT 
  u.fullname, 
  ROUND(AVG(r.correct), 2) avg_correct, 
  date_format(any_value(r.time_taken),'%d-%m-%Y') time_taken
FROM (SELECT user_id, concat( first_name, ' ', last_name) fullname from user) u
LEFT JOIN test_result r ON u.user_id = r.user_id
GROUP BY r.user_id, u.fullname
ORDER BY time_taken DESC
```

You can find more here: [MySQL Handling of GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html)

Comment: After executing the query getting this error: FUNCTION db_test.any_value does not exist @forpas

Comment: Why? What is your version of Mysql? ANY_VALUE is there since 5.7 (or before?).

Comment: Anyway, replace: `any_value(r.time_taken)` with `max(r.time_taken)` or `min(r.time_taken)`

Comment: MySQL Version: `10.1.37-MariaDB` but `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` is disabled

Comment: Your tag is MySql. I know MariaDB did not support any_value() and maybe still does not. Instead use min() or max().

Comment: Thanks for your time and reply @forpas

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend writing this query as:

```
SELECT CONCAT(u.first_name, ' ', u.last_name) as fullname,
       ROUND(AVG(r.correct), 2) as avg_correct,  
       DATE_FORMAT(MAX(r.time_taken), '%d-%m-%Y') as time_taken
FROM user u LEFT JOIN
     test_result r
     ON u.user_id = r.user_id
GROUP BY u.user_id, fullname
ORDER BY MAX(r.time_taken) DESC;
```

Notes:

- The subquery in the `FROM` clause does not help the query.  It might impede the optimizer.
- Don't `GROUP BY` columns from the *second* table in a `LEFT JOIN` (unless you really know what you are doing).  The value would be `NULL` for non-matches.
- MySQL and MariaDB allow column aliases in the `GROUP BY` clause.
- For the `ORDER BY` to work as you intend, it needs to be on the value *before* formatting, not after formatting.  The format `%d-%m-%Y` does not order by time.