# result changing after adding more column

Tags: mysql, sql

I am playing with the city table on the world database in MYSQL and I am having some strange results which I know are wrong. I want to know why that is happening and how to solve the situation.

```
select max(population) from city
## answer##
10500000 ##
```

which is the population of mumbai and when try to tie name to it here is what I get:

```
select, name, max(population) from city
## answer##
Kabul   10500000 ### which is not the population Kabul###
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33629201/5070879  `The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate` - Long story short, for every major RDBMS second query is invalid.

Comment: If you only need a single row as result, then use a (trivial) `ORDER BY ... LIMIT 1` query.

Comment: You haven't said what you do want..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query:

```
select, name, max(population)
from city
```

does not make sense.  It is an aggregation query (because of the `max()`).  It will return exactly one row (because there is no `group by`).  But what value of `name`?

Well, in standard SQL, almost all databases, and the most recent versions of MySQL (with default settings), it returns an error, to the effect of "`name` is not being aggregated".

Older versions of MySQL allow this construct, and choose a value of `name` from an arbitrary and indeterminate row in the data.

What you seem to really want is:

```
select name, population
from city
order by population desc
limit 1;
```

Answer (score -1):

The correct syntax for your second query would be -

```
SELECT name, MAX(population)
FROM city
GROUP BY name;
```