# Where condition not working with the group by

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables which are `tbl_lead, tbl_documentsPickup` and `tbl_bankdata`.

`tbl_lead` table is connected with `tbl_documentsPickup` with `lead_id` same with `tbl_bankdata`. I have personal information on `tbl_lead` table, document informiton on `tbl_documentsPickup` and bank infromation on `tbl_bankdata`. Bank information can have more then one records.

Now I have to display the records from all the tables so I am using `joins` and `group by`.

Why `group by` because of In the `tbl_bankdata` i have more than one record of the same user. So I have to group the lead_id.

I have 3 records in `tbl_lead` , 3 records in `tbl_documentsPickup` and 5 records on `tbl_bankdata`. I am getting the 3 records using group by which is correct.

SO my query is,

```
SELECT * 
  FROM tbl_lead 
  LEFT JOIN tbl_documentsPickup ON tbl_lead.c_id=tbl_documentsPickup.lead_id  
  LEFT JOIN (
             SELECT lead_id, b_bankDoneStatus, max(date_of_added) as latest 
               FROM tbl_bankdata 
              GROUP BY lead_id) r 
         ON tbl_lead.c_id=r.lead_id  
      ORDER BY tbl_lead.date_of_created DESC;
```

Using the above code I am getting my correct output. I am getting each record. Now I have to set the where condition.

my issue is, I have a column called `statusDone` in the table `tbl_bankdata`. If the statusDone is 0 then display the records else not to display the records.

I tried

If I use statusDone=0 with the group by then I am getting all the records or If I use r.statusDone=0 then I am getting the error `Unknown column 'r.statusDone' in 'where clause'`

I am using Codeigniter. I just shared my SQL query.

Comment: Subquery itself looks fishy: `select lead_id, b_bankDoneStatus, max(date_of_added) as latest from tbl_bankdata group by lead_id` `b_bankDoneStatus` is not wrapped by aggregate function and I doubt it is functionally dependent on lead_id column. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33629201/5070879

Comment: @LukaszSzozda, Can you help me with correct subquery?

Comment: The first thing you should do is to provide http://dbfiddle.uk demo with sample data and desired result. Working on actual curated code is much easier than long description.

Comment: @LukaszSzozda, Yes I agree with your last comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to include `statusDone` column within the subquery(also within the `GROUP BY list`) :

```
SELECT * 
   FROM tbl_lead l
   LEFT JOIN tbl_documentsPickup dp ON l.c_id = dp.lead_id  
   LEFT JOIN (
              SELECT lead_id, statusDone, max(date_of_added) as latest 
                FROM tbl_bankdata 
               GROUP BY lead_id, statusDone     
              HAVING max(`date_of_added`) = latest              
              ) bd 
          ON l.c_id = bd.lead_id 
       WHERE bd.statusDone = 0
       ORDER BY l.date_of_created DESC;
```

Comment: give me some time to check your answer

Comment: I am getting all the records. why you used max(b_bankDoneStatus)=0 ?

Comment: @questionbank Is statusDone  = b_bankDoneStatus ..? and does tbl_bankdata really has a column called statusDone or is it just an alias ?

Comment: no both are different. I have to set the condition on statusDone which is also in tbl_bankdata table

Comment: @questionbank then, it seems you need to consider `having max(statusDone)=0 `

Comment: I tried but it's not working. I am getting all 3 records. It should be 2 records because of one record statusDone=1

Comment: @questionbank Does statusDone=1 belong to only a unique lead_id , or the same lead_id is shared by some other row with statusDone=1 ?

Comment: Currently  Yes, but in future no.  Because in the tbl_bankdata I am inserting the bank data which is more than one of any lead id but all the bank records are corrected with lead id.

Comment: lead_id is the id of the personal information which is on tbl_lead.

Comment: I tried but I am getting error   #1054 - Unknown column 'r.statusDone' in 'on clause'.    I checked in the table column name is there.

Comment: but I added `statusDone` column within the subquery.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197788/discussion-between-questionbank-and-barbaros-ozhan).

Comment: Whatever the solution, I'm sure that `SELECT *` need be no part of it. :-(