# Which row is selected in GROUP BY?

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I have a table

```
+------+---------+--------+
| lang | title   | url    |
+------+---------+--------+
| pt   | Livro 1 | o294jl |
| en   | Book 1  | o294jl |
| en   | Book 2  | o294jl |
+------+---------+--------+
```

And I run a query

```sql
SELECT lang, title
FROM table
GROUP BY url
```

The result of the query is not obvious because the values of `lang` and `title` are different among the group.

How does an SQL engine choose which row to return from a group? Which row must be selected in my example? Is it specified in the SQL standard?

Comment: [Group by clause in mySQL and postgreSQL, why the error in postgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33629201/5070879) - this query is not a valid one according to the standard with `sql_mode = ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` you will get an error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Values are chosen from *arbitrary* matching rows for each group.  The values could come from different rows for different runs.  In theory, different columns in the same `SELECT` could come from different rows.

The documentation explains this:

> If `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` is disabled, a MySQL extension to the standard
>   SQL use of `GROUP BY` permits the select list, `HAVING` condition, or
>   ORDER BY list to refer to nonaggregated columns even if the columns
>   are not functionally dependent on `GROUP BY` columns. . . . **In this case, the server is free to
>   choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the
>   values chosen are nondeterministic, which is probably not what you
>   want.**

You should read the complete [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html) on the subject.

Note that the default behavior of MySQL is now to reject such queries.  Yay!

Answer (score 1):

I addition to Gorden's answer – In practice the engine will just do the least work, which is to choose the values from the first found row in the group. However – Which row is the first depends on the execution plan, in particular on the chosen index.

Assuming the following schema and data:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  `lang`  VARCHAR(2),
  `title` VARCHAR(50),
  `url`   VARCHAR(50)
) engine=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO test (`lang`, `title`, `url`) VALUES
  ('pt', 'Livro 1', 'o294jl'),
  ('en', 'Book 1', 'o294jl'),
  ('en', 'Book 2', 'o294jl');
```

Executing the query

```
SELECT lang, title FROM test GROUP BY url;
```

returns

```
| lang | title   |
| ---- | ------- |
| pt   | Livro 1 |
```

Which is the first row in insertion order (using the clustered index).

If we now define an index on `(url, lang, title)`

```
ALTER TABLE test ADD INDEX url_lang_title (url, lang, title);
```

The same SELECT query returns

```
| lang | title  |
| ---- | ------ |
| en   | Book 1 |
```

which is the first row in the new `url_lang_title` index.

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6SrSEPxBfEHLQUAxXMmnE1/0)

As you can see: Having exactly same data and exactly same query – MySQL can return different results. And even if you don't change the indices, you can't rely on a particular index being chosen. The engine can choose another index for many other reasons.

The moral of the story: Don't ask what the engine will return. Instead tell it exactly what you want it to return by writing deterministic queries.