# Is it necessary to use group by when we have 2 cols in select and 1 of them has min/max aggregate function on it, if all we need is 1st column's id?

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I have a OrderDetails table like shown here (click on OrderDetails table on the right) https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_op_in

**I want to select productID with max number of quantity**

I went thru this answer [Is it possible to use Aggregate function in a Select statment without using Group By clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6467216/is-it-possible-to-use-aggregate-function-in-a-select-statment-without-using-grou),

so this answer makes sense if I am summing/averaging something then putting the other column(without aggregation) in a group by clause

for example

```
select depName, avg(salary)
from department
```

here you're averaging without group by so the query is ambiguous that avg of what depName ?

but the following query is what I am talking about if I have a situation like this (OrderDetails table and select ID of max quantity)  can I use the below query ?

```
select ProductID, max(Quantity)
from 
OrderDetails
```

the query shown above gives me desired result,
it gives me the ID which has the max quantity. 
I know there are other ways of performing the same query like put them and desc. order select top 1st row's id etc..

any help will be appreciated
Thanks !

Comment: you can actually try running on the 1st link from the question, havent tried on mysql workbench tho

Comment: `select ProductId, max(Quantity) from OrderDetails` does *not* return the ProductId associated with the row that has the max Quantity value unless by accident. It returns the ProductId of the first row.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are actually asking. You seem to know that you can use `LIMIT 1` (or `TOP 1` for sql-server). See: [which-row-is-selected-in-group-by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57637335/which-row-is-selected-in-group-by)

Comment: You need `select ProductId, Quantity from OrderDetails where Quantity = (select max(Quantity) from OrderDetails));` This can return multiple rows unless you put a limit on it.

Comment: @RonaldAaronson that's what I was thinking , I mean if I do sum() or avg() 1st row's id is returned, but not in this case

Comment: MySQL and SqlLite are too loose when it comes to syntax rules and restrictions, `select ProductId, max(Quantity) from OrderDetails` is not the correct syntax.

Comment: @Anuj I suppose it depends on what is meant by "first row", i.e. whether ProductId is your primary key or not. I just tested this on a similar table where I did a `select a, max(b) from t` where a is a primary key and if I do a `select * from t` without specifying s sort order the first value of `a` that is returned is what I call the `a of the first row`. In any case, what you will get is a crap shoot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's how SQL works: `max, min, avg ... etc` are called aggregate functions and they require `group by` clause to work when the query have them beside another column in the projection.

Your query `SELECT c1, max(c2) from T1;` is still ambiguous as you might have more than c1 values which have the `max(c2)` in the table, it could have been implemented to return more than one row, but this is NOT how SQL was designed.

When you use aggregate functions you specify `GROUP BY` to select your ranges where a single value of the aggregate function is returned for each range.

The way to get the result you want is like this:

```
SELECT ProductId, Quantity 
FROM OrderDetails 
WHERE Quantity = (SELECT MAX(Quantity) FROM OrderDetails);
```

Comment: okay i get it why it's ambiguous  but in your case too where Quantity =  there can be more than 2 quantities which have same highest value but different productIDs then ?

Comment: yes and here you are selecting all of them, look at `SELECT ProductId, Quantity ` this projection has no aggregates so it's free to return all the rows matching the criteria.

Comment: Thanks makes sense :) appreciate for your help