# Query to split even and odd numbers, with GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have a query that finds housenumbers per street in a specific postcode with four numbers:

```
SELECT *,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CAST(housenumber AS int) ORDER BY housenumber ASC) AS housenumbers
FROM streets
WHERE postcode LIKE '3031%'
GROUP BY street
ORDER BY lat,lon
```

This is the result of the groupcatted housenumbers.

```
491,492,493,500,501,502,503,504,505,506,507,508,50
```

I would like to split the result, over two columns, in evenhousenumber and oddhousenumbers.
I tried `MOD` and `%2`, but both require a `WHERE` and it's not possible to use the `WHERE` in the groupcat function, I noticed.

How can I split the result, over even and odd numbers?

Comment: Why would you be converting the housenumbers to integers to concatenate them into a string?

Comment: Because I want to have a short list, that's printable. For delivery of flyers door-to-door, it's not essential to have all the letters etc. on the list.

Comment: something called house**number** has values other than numbers?

Comment: @GordonLinoff, It's not uncommon for a second home unit to exist at the same address, and they are lettered. Like "221B Baker Street", the address of detective Sherlock Holmes.

Answer (score 5):

You could use `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT street
 ,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN MOD(CAST(housenumber AS int),2) = 0 THEN CAST(housenumber AS int) END ORDER BY housenumber ASC) AS housenumbers_even
 ,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN MOD(CAST(housenumber AS int),2) = 1 THEN CAST(housenumber AS int) END ORDER BY housenumber ASC) AS housenumbers_odd
FROM streets
WHERE postcode LIKE '3031%'
GROUP BY street
ORDER BY lat,lon;
```

It works because [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) skips `NULL` values.

---

Also `SELECT * ... GROUP BY street` is not safe. Related: [Group by clause in mySQL and postgreSQL, why the error in postgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33629168/group-by-clause-in-mysql-and-postgresql-why-the-error-in-postgresql/33629201#33629201)

Comment: Amazing you are so fast Lukasz. I didn't knew GROUP_CONCAT skips NULL and that a CASE could be used in GROUP_CONCAT. Thanks for the excellent answer.

Comment: @JeroenSteen Glad to hear I could help :)

Comment: @JeroenSteen pretty much all aggregate functions sklp null values (only yielding null if every value encountered is null).

Comment: Hi @Strawberry ! Thanks for your concern. No my account wasn't hacked(I hope so). Could you elaborate what does seem odd for you? Myabe I am unaware of sth.

Comment: @Strawberry Yes, I got your point. Unless street is unique(all columns are functionally dependent on that column).

Comment: @Strawberry "Also, I see no CASE expression here " `CASE WHEN MOD(CAST(housenumber AS int),2) = 0 THEN CAST(housenumber AS int) END`?

Comment: Ah , it falls off the page in my tiny viewer

Comment: @Strawberry No worries, thank you for nitpicking :)