# How can I group data from multiple rows into the same row?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query:

```
select * from dwtrat_edu_tempdb.test1
```

That returns

```
tile_to_update elementary_school   high_school   university
2270210        583                 null          null
2270210        321                 10529         null
2270210        null                null          58151
```

I want to combine the rows and take one value from each column (doesn't matter which, first, last, can be any) So one elementary school, one high school, one university.

It would look like:

```
tile_to_update elementary_school   high_school   university
2270210        583                 10529         58151
```

However, when I try to group by:

```
select * from dwtrat_edu_tempdb.test1 
group by tile_to_update
```

I'm getting only a value for one of the columns and not a combination of all

```
tile_to_update elementary_school   high_school   university
2270210        null                10529         null
```

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about any specific value then [`ANY_VALUE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_any-value)/MIN/MAX is an option:

```
select tile_to_update,
       ANY_VALUE(elementary_school),ANY_VALUE(high_school),ANY_VALUE(university) 
from dwtrat_edu_tempdb.test1 
group by tile_to_update
```

Comment: Hi Lukasz I apologize I should have added this is in Sqlite. I was hoping there is something basic I am overlooking that would make this a simple query.

Comment: @johnwilliams Then change `ANY_VALUE` to `MIN/MAX`

Comment: Ah, that worked. Thank you so much. Is there somewhere you can recommend I can read about why the select without min/max doesn't take a value from each column. My brain expects it would but I can't seem to wrap my head around why the min/max is required to make this query work. Or would you mind explaining?

Comment: @johnwilliams I suggest reading: [Group by clause in mySQL and postgreSQL, why the error in postgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33629168/group-by-clause-in-mysql-and-postgresql-why-the-error-in-postgresql/33629201#33629201)

Comment: Much appreciated. I will read that. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Please try below query as well and let me know is it working for you or not.

```
SELECT DISTINCT tile_to_update
  ,COALESCE(elementary_school)
  ,COALESCE(high_school)
  ,COALESCE(university)
FROM dwtrat_edu_tempdb.test1
```

Answer (score 0):

Lukasz Szozda answered your question as asked; however, since you have more than 1 not null value per column, I can almost guarantee you are setting yourself up for failure because this results in unnecessary data loss.  Instead of returning a single value using ANY_VALUE(), MIN(), MAX(), or COALESCE(), you may actually wish to use GROUP_CONCAT so that you can generate lists of values like this:

```
SELECT tile_to_update, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(elementary_school),
  GROUP_CONCAT(high_school),
  GROUP_CONCAT(university)
FROM dwtrat_edu_tempdb.test1
GROUP BY tile_to_update
```

Results in:

```
"tile_to_update"=>"2270210", "elementary_school" =>"583, 321", "high_school" =>"10529",  "university" =>"10529
```