# Why can't select records for each code having the maximum date with having date=max(date)?

Tags: mysql, subquery, groupwise-maximum

Show create table structure with;

```
CREATE TABLE `quote` (
  `id` int(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `code` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `open` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `high` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `low` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `close` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `volume` bigint(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=17449887 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Find the records for each code having the maximum date with inner join such as:

```
SELECT q1.*
FROM quote q1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT code, MAX(date) AS max_date
    FROM quote
    GROUP BY code
) q2
    ON q2.code = q1.code AND
       q2.max_date = q1.date;
```

I wonder why the subquery can't get desired result as above:

```
select * from quote group by code having date=max(date);
```

Please explain the reason in detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wonder why the subquery can't get desired result as above:
>
> ```
> select * from quote group by code having date=max(date);
> ```

To start with:

```
select * from quote group by code
```

This query itself is not a valid one from SQL Standard perspective.

It could be, if all other columns were functionally dependent on `code`, which is not the case based on table definition(code is not unique and not a primary key). Related reading: [Group by clause in mySQL and postgreSQL, why the error in postgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33629168/group-by-clause-in-mysql-and-postgresql-why-the-error-in-postgresql/33629201#33629201)

The query behaves kind of [ANY_VALUE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_any-value):

```
select code, ANY_VALUE(id), ANY_VALUE(`date`), ANY_VALUE(`open`)...
from quote
group by code
```

Regarding second part:

```
having date=max(date);
--
having any_value(date) = max(date) -- sidenote: it will work for single row per `code`
```

Here the condition in **`HAVING` applies after aggregation**, which means the comparison is between MAX(date) per code compared to "unspecified" date.

---

Illustrating with example(this code will work only if `only_full_group_by` is turned off):

```
CREATE TABLE `quote` (
  `id` int(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `code` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `open` double DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ;

INSERT INTO quote(`code`, `date`, `open`)
VALUES ('a', '2020-01-01',10),
       ('a', '2021-01-01',20),
       ('a', '2022-01-01',30);
```

And queries:

```
SELECT * FROM quote;
+-----+-------+-------------+------+
| id  | code  |    date     | open |
+-----+-------+-------------+------+
|  1  | a     | 2020-01-01  |   10 |
|  2  | a     | 2021-01-01  |   20 |
|  3  | a     | 2022-01-01  |   30 |
+-----+-------+-------------+------+

select * from quote group by code;

-- this part is unspecified, id/date/open are arbitrary
+-----+-------+-------------+------+
| id  | code  |    date     | open |
+-----+-------+-------------+------+
|  1  | a     | 2020-01-01  |    1 |
+-----+-------+-------------+------+

select *, MAX(date) from quote group by code;

-- MAX(date) is stable, date is arbitrary, comparison does not make sense at this point
+-----+-------+-------------+-------+------------+
| id  | code  |    date     | open  | MAX(date)  |
+-----+-------+-------------+-------+------------+
|  1  | a     | 2020-01-01  |   10  | 2022-01-01 |  
+-----+-------+-------------+-------+------------+

select * from quote group by code having date=max(date);

-- empty
+-----+-------+-------+------+
| id  | code  | date  | open |
+-----+-------+-------+------+
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=69c68edcfe6032bebf08ed359aa9383d)**

---

Saying so, in order to get all columns [ranking functions MySQL 8.0+](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html) could be used:

> This section describes **nonaggregate window functions that, for each row from a query, perform a calculation using rows related to that row**

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY `code` ORDER BY `date` DESC) AS rn
      FROM `quote`) s   --RANK() if `date` is not unique per code
WHERE rn = 1;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo 2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=602e12c75d972a5fc6ea0d3e4526db7a)**

Answer (score 2):

This

```
select * from quote group by code having date=max(date);
```

has `max(date)` which makes sense in the context of `GROUP BY code`.  But `date` does not.  The issue is *which* row's `date` should be compared?  Simply put, it is probably 'invalid' SQL.

See also discussions of "only_full_group_by".  (Newer versions of MySQL would flag your query as invalid.  That flag is a way to turn it off to get the old, wrong, evaluation.)

That leads to subqueries, such as the one you have.  There are a few others.  Here is my catalog of the optimal ways to do groupwise-max:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max

There are also many discussions; see the tag `[groupwise-maximum]` that I added.

Other issues:  Is `code` a ticker symbol?  If so, it does not need to be `TEXT`.  By changing to, say, `VARCHAR(15)`, you can gain a lot of performance:

Get rid of `id` and change to `PRIMARY KEY(code, date)`.  This will spread up that subquery *significantly* and will probably improve some other queries.

Answer (score 1):

@scrapy I believe the answer to your question has to do with the difference between having a sub-query vs how the other query is structured. The way having a sub-query works is MySQL creates a derived table from the query before the outer query is run, then the derived table is used when MySQL executes the outer query ([here's the documentation on derived tables for you to refer to](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html)).

The sub query you have works because you are only selecting 1 column (`code`) and then you are getting an aggregate value from using the `MAX(date)` as your second column and lastly you are grouping by `code` on the last line of your sub-query.

In your second query, you are using `SELECT *` and then grouping by just `code` before you try to use the `MAX(date)` in your `HAVING` clause. This query doesn't work because you are selecting every column in the table by using `SELECT *` but you are only grouping by `code` in your `GROUP BY` clause. Starting in MySQL v5.7 and beyond there is something called `only_full_group_by` that does not allow you to run a query using `GROUP BY` unless you specify every column in your `SELECT` statement in your `GROUP BY`, IE: to get your second query to work you would have to have every column in your table listed in your `GROUP BY` clause because you are using a `SELECT *` for your select statement ([here is the documentation that talks about only_full_group_by](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html)).

And lastly, in order to get the result set you are looking for you have to group by the right columns, like you are doing in your sub-query. If you use anything other than `code` in a query where you try to get the max date per `code`, the result set will not be the same because you would have to group by the extra columns which would throw off your result set.