# Aggregation with required columns in GROUP BY clause in postgresSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

**[DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=ed57a2f36d4d4776e733bb17785e6810)**

```
CREATE TABLE sales (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    campaign VARCHAR,
    sales_channel VARCHAR,
    product VARCHAR,
    quantity DECIMAL
);

INSERT INTO sales
(campaign,  sales_channel, product, quantity)
VALUES 
('C001', 'online', 'product_04', '800'),
('C001', 'online', 'product_03', '300'),
('C001', 'online', 'product_02', '200'),

('C002', 'retail', 'product_05', '500'),
('C002', 'retail', 'product_04', '600'),
('C002', 'retail', 'product_03', '600'),
('C002', 'retail', 'product_03', '600'),
('C002', 'retail', 'product_02', '600'),

('C003', 'fair', 'product_07', '600'),
('C003', 'fair', 'product_01', '400');
```

**Expected Result:**

```
campaign |  sales_channel |   product     |     quantity  |
---------|----------------|---------------|---------------|---
C001     |      online    |   product_04  |     1.300     |
C002     |      retail    |   product_05  |     2.900     |
C003     |      fair      |   product_07  |     1.000     |
```

---

To get the expected result I tried to go wiht this query:

```
SELECT 
s.campaign AS campaign,
s.sales_channel AS sales_channel,
s.product AS product,
SUM(s.quantity) AS quantity
FROM sales s
GROUP BY 1;
```

However, it gives me error: `column s.sales_channe" must appear in the GROUP BY clause`. 
The problem is when I add the `sales_channel` to the `GROUP BY` clause I am not able to ge the expected result because then it groups both by `campaign` and `sales_channel`.

How do I have to modify the query to get the expected result as in **[MariaDB](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=b503b3a7a3d5c4ce3483b15c7fe689a3)**?

Comment: [Group by clause in mySQL and postgreSQL, why the error in postgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33629168/group-by-clause-in-mysql-and-postgresql-why-the-error-in-postgresql)

Comment: [db<>fiddle demo MariaDB with ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=02d6c391d57bc6a27837beb459c5f511)  => Same error: "s.sales_channel' isn't in GROUP BY"

Comment: Please explain the logic you want to implement.  It is not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to aggregate sales_channel and product in some way.  For sales_channel, it doesn't really matter how you aggregate it, because there's only one option per campaign.  Product, on the other hand, has multiple options.  It appears that you want the maximum product, so choose that:

```
SELECT 
s.campaign AS campaign,
max(s.sales_channel) AS sales_channel,
max(s.product) AS product,
SUM(s.quantity) AS quantity
FROM sales s
GROUP BY 1;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=b34e3dc89b3fed651e66b428c2d8f0c4)

Comment: For my own documenation: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=0c1edf0f800ea310eda4acda315acfbd

Answer (score 0):

You may want the most common product.  SYou can get this with two levels of aggregation:

```
SELECT s.campaign AS campaign, s.sales_channel AS sales_channel,
       MAX(s.product) FILTER (WHERE seqnum = 1) AS mode_product,
       SUM(s.quantity) AS quantity
FROM (SELECT campaign, sales_channel, product, SUM(quantity) as quantity,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY campaign, sales_channel ORDER BY SUM(quantity) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM sales s
      GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
     ) s
GROUP BY 1, 2
ORDER BY s.campaign;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=b57e5d59f60f3e96f871303e61b12317) is a db<>fiddle.